# If the socket() function fails should I close the socket?

Tags: c, sockets

If the `socket()` function fails and returns `-1`, should I close the socket or not because it already couldn't create a socket?

Comment: You can't close the socket, because you have no socket to close.

Comment: Which socket would you close?

Comment: Do you expect `close(-1);` to do anything else than return `-1` and set `errno` to `EBADF`?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously if `socket()` returned `-1` you do not have a valid handle to pass to `close()`. So no, there is no need to close the socket, it was not created. The same applies to `open()` or `creat()` retuning `-1`.

Note that if you inadvertently pass `-1` to `close()`, nothing bad will happen as the OS will just report an invalid handle, which the C library system call wrapper will handle by returning `-1` setting `errno` to `EBADF`.

This is in contrast to passing `fclose()` the null stream pointer returned by `fopen()` in case of failure: The C Standard explicitly says this has undefined behavior and some implementations will not check for a null pointer and cause a segmentation fault by dereferencing the null pointer, thus terminating the program.

Also note that if `bind()`, `listen()` or `connect()` fail on a valid socket handle returned by `socket()`, then you do need to close the socket when done with it, after potentially retrying these calls.

Comment: Note that if `bind` or `listen` or `connect` fails then you _do_ need to close the socket.

Comment: @zwol: good point, answer amended.

Comment: @MrBen: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.